# Import library of php to laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I had a problem importing libraries into the Laravel project. I want to use the image_QRCode-0.1.3 library coded in php used in Project Laravel.

`https://pear.php.net/package/Image_QRCode/download`

but when I use the require command in class QRCodeController

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

require_once "../../../Library/Image_QRCode-0.1.3/Image_QRCode-0.1.3/Image/QRCode.php";

class QRCodeController extends Controller {
    public function genQRCode()
    {
        $QR = new \Image_QRCode();
        $option = array(
            'module_size' => 4,
            'image_type' => 'png',
            'output_type' => 'display',
            'error_correct' => 'H',
        );

        $qrcode = $QR->makeCode(htmlspecialchars("https://blog.shnr.net/?p=526", ENT_QUOTES), $option);
    } 
}
```

The program did not run and reported an error.

Please help me, thanks you so much !

Comment: Post the actual error, and where did you write the `require_once`

Comment: Why don't you get it from composer? `composer require pear/image_qrcode` and add it using `use Pear\Image_QRCode()`

Comment: @senty because I have to use version 0.1.3 of Image QRCode

Comment: I think I know why. Can your Laravel application access to `../../../Library`? Try to put it somewhere else, maybe inside App/Services/ - Have a read: [Use an external PHP file in Controller](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/)

Comment: @senty I tried, but the program still error

Comment: Well, what's the error?

Comment: Post the error code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use external classes or any other PHP library into your Laravel project, you have to do the following steps:

**1. Create a folder somewhere in your Laravel app that will contain the PHP files you're going to use:**

For example you have a custom class, create a folder in the directory `app/libraries`. Inside `app/libraries`, paste the PHP files you'll be using (the library files you've downloaded).

**2. In your `composer.json` file, add the folder/directory into your autoload classmap:**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libraries", <------------------ YOUR CUSTOM DIRECTORY
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
        ]
    }
```

**3. Once you're done, just run `composer dump-autoload` and you should be able to call your class as follows:**

Assuming your class name is `SomeClass.php` and it's inside the `app/libraries` directory and you're properly namespaced the class you've just copied over, you can now use `SomeClass.php` anywhere you need it.

```
$class = new \some_class_namespace\SomeClass();
```

You can also give it an alias in your `config/app.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => [
    ....
    'SomeAlias' => 'app\libraries\SomeClass',
    ....
],
```

After then you can instantiate the class from anywhere in your application just like any other classes:

```
$class = new SomeAlias();
```

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I want